# Android API 33 source downloaded but some source code is missing. why?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-source

When using Android Studio, one can download SDK source code.
On Windows, downloaded source code is located here:

```
C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\
```

But I observed that, for API 33, *for some classes*, the source code is not present in this (usual) location.

**Example:**

For the class `android.provider.OpenableColumns` source is present here

```
C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-33\android\provider\OpenableColumns.java
```

which is fine :-)

But for the class `android.provider.MediaStore`, source is **NOT present** at the expected location:

```
 ̶C̶:̶\̶U̶s̶e̶r̶s̶\̶<̶U̶S̶E̶R̶>̶\̶A̶p̶p̶D̶a̶t̶a̶\̶L̶o̶c̶a̶l̶\̶A̶n̶d̶r̶o̶i̶d̶\̶S̶d̶k̶\̶s̶o̶u̶r̶c̶e̶s̶\̶a̶n̶d̶r̶o̶i̶d̶-̶3̶3̶\̶a̶n̶d̶r̶o̶i̶d̶\̶p̶r̶o̶v̶i̶d̶e̶r̶\̶M̶e̶d̶i̶a̶S̶t̶o̶r̶e̶.̶j̶a̶v̶a̶
```

**Questions:**

- Is it related to the new [extension mechanism](https://developer.android.com/guide/sdk-extensions)? I suppose so.
- How can I, from withing Android Studio, get and see missing source code (in my example, source code of `android.provider.MediaStore` ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

PS:
[issue created on issuetracker.google.com](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/287110098)

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK 34 revision 2 source code does not have this problem.
(see issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/287110098 )

As of now, Android SDK 33 is the minimum **target SDK** we must use (see https://developer.android.com/google/play/requirements/target-sdk#why-target ) but soon it will be SDK 34.

**Solution:**

Using **compileSdkVersion = 34** does solve this issue: `android.provider.MediaStore` source is back :-)
(and all other missing sources)

Up to you to decide whether or not you **also** change targetSdkVersion to 34 (or keep 33).
If so, make sure to check this page: [Migrate apps to Android 14](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/migration)